# Login alert from external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a `alert` if the password is incorrect and required fields are not given using jQuery.
I strucked on some logic.

Thanks in advance..

**index.php**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required="" id = "stu_id" placeholder=" Id">
<input class="form-control" type="password" required="" id = "passwd" placeholder="Password">

<a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="stu_login();"  type="submit">Log In</a>

//here i want to display alert if required fields and password is incorrect
<div align ="right" id = "login_status"> </div>
```

This is my **login_check.js**

```
function stu_login() {
  var stu_id = $("#stu_id").val();
  var stu_passwd = $("#passwd").val();

  if(stu_id == "")
  {
    $("#login_status").html('<div class="info" id="sa-basic">Please enter your ID to proceed.</div>');
    $("#stu_id").focus();

    else if(stu_passwd == "")
    {
      $("#login_status").html('<div class="info" id="sa-basic">Please enter 
      your account password to go.</div>');
      $("#passwd").focus();
    }
    else
    {
      var dataString = 'stu_id=' + stu_id + '&passwd=' + stu_passwd + '&page=users_login';
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login_check.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
          $("#login_status").html('<br clear="all"><br clear="all"><div 
          align="left"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
          font-size:15px; color:black;">Please wait</font> <img 
          src="images/loadings.gif" alt="Loading...." align="absmiddle" 
          title="Loading...."/></div><br clear="all">');
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
          var response_brought = response.indexOf('login_process_completed_successfully=yes');
          if (response_brought != -1) 
          {
            $("#login_status").html('');
            //window.location.replace(response);
            window.location ="home.php";
          }
          else
          {
            $("#login_status").fadeIn(1000).html(response);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

**In the code I can easily display message from `login_check.js` to `index.html`, but I don't know how to give the alert from alert.js.** I want to replace message from `login_check.js` and make a pop up alert.

Here is my **alert.js**

```
!function ($) {
"use strict";

var SweetAlert = function () {
};

SweetAlert.prototype.init = function () {

  //Basic
  $('#sa-basic').click(function () {
    swal("Here's a message!");
  });
  //init
  $.SweetAlert = new SweetAlert, $.SweetAlert.Constructor = SweetAlert
}(window.jQuery),

//initializing 
function ($) {
  "use strict";
  $.SweetAlert.init()
}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>sweetAlert({
    title: "Oops!",
    text: "Something went wrong on the page!", 
    type: "error"
   });</script>
```

Changed in the **$(#login_status).html ()**

```
   $(#login_status).html ('<script>sweetAlert({
    title: "Oops!",
    text: "Something went wrong on the page!", 
    type: "error"
   });</script>')
```